# What's the strongest way to bond a cable stop to an steel frame?

Tags: brakes, cable, steel, cable-housing, cable-routing

I have a steel single speed bike and want to add a rear brake. All is good expect there is no cable stops on the top tube. I want to bond two cable stops to the under side of the top tube.

Answer (score 20):

Don't use cable stops.  The biggest load those stops will ever see is when you grab your brakes hard for an emergency stop.  So you're likely to find out that whatever you did to bond the stops to the frame wasn't strong enough or fatigue-resistant enough at the absolute worst possible time.

And you'll ***never*** be able to know if your work is fatigue-resistant enough.  You can only find out that it ***wasn't*** - and you'll know that only after it fails.

Run the outer housing the entire length of the cable.  All you need then is a few tie wraps to hold the cable near the frame.

Comment: If you want something that looks more finished than zip-ties, you can get old-school clamp-on cable guides, but they're functionally identical.

Comment: Unless the bonding technique is 'welding' or 'brazing'. Then you can be pretty sure the bonds are strong enough.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus  If you're practiced at doing that...

Comment: Another alternative to cable ties is duct tape in the color of the frame. Or simply wrap the outer housing around the top tube, the steering tube and saddle tube/post will stop it from unwinding. The later has the advantage to allow for very easy repairs, but it does have a bit of a make-shift look to it.

Comment: +1 for just running the outer housing the whole length. However, I would contradict your assertion that the biggest brake-load is at an emergency stop. A properly working brake system should lock the wheels and/or throw you over the bars if you ever put maximum force on it, and it's part of the essential skills of cycling to _regularly practice_ going to the maximum safe brake pressure, so you can get that pressure right even at an emergency. So, the brake stops should fail during one of these practice sessions (and then you'll still have the front brake left), if there really is a weakness.

Comment: In other words: maximum brake efficiency is not achieved at maximum brake pressure. In a car or modern motorcycle, the anti-locking brake system is responsible for dialling in the right pressure in an emergency; in a bicycle the rider must do that.

Comment: @leftaroundabout But no one practices modulating the *rear* brake.

Comment: @AndrewHenle maybe roadies don't. They should, though, because a locked out rear wheel makes steering very unstable during the brake maneuver, which is not something you should add to the danger in an emergency situation.

Comment: Honestly, this answer is just fear mongering. The fact that cable stops exist at all should be enough evidence that they work and can be used safely. Just because it has a potential for being a failure point, doesn't mean it can't be designed around. That said, the correct answer is as Argenti Apparatus says: welding or brazing

Comment: @Phill *The fact that cable stops exist at all should be enough evidence that they work and can be used safely.* So anybody can safely use any technology?  Are you a Boeing manager?  *Just because it has a potential for being a failure point, doesn't mean it can't be designed around.*  Umm, no.  Proper design is necessary for safety, but it's not sufficient. Implementation is just as important. What's the proper pre-treatment for the bicycle frame in qeustion before it can be safely welded/brazed?  **You don't even know what the frame is actually made of.**

Comment: @AndrewHenle, the question literally says steel frame in the title

Comment: @Phill [Steel, you say?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_steel_grades)  They have to be treated differently when welded.  So which "steel" is that frame made from?  **You don't know**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, it's not like the type of steel is unknowable, especially if you know anything about the frame. Anyway, the point is, if you want to take this route, it's totally possible for it to work and be safe. Can/should any one do it? No, you need to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 16):

Beside a professionally done welding, clamp-on cable stops should be a reasonably reliable solution.

[image: Problem solvers]

[image: Origin8]

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have the cable stops? If not, then you might consider looking for ones that are attached by rivets. That will reduce the amount of skill and tools you'll need and will still give you a pretty strong bond (although it probably won't be the strongest as per your question, that is still probably welding or brazing). You'll need to make sure the rivets are the right size for the depth and diameter of the hole, as well as being thick enough to withstand the shear forces.

The ones sold [here](https://www.cycle-frames.com/NOVA-CABLE-STOP-SINGLE-RIVET-BLK.html) have holes for two 1/8" rivets.
[image]

If you go this route, I strongly encourage you do your own calculations, but as a rough guide [according to NASA](https://msis.jsc.nasa.gov/sections/section04.htm) the 95 percentile maximum grip strength for males is 729N. On my bike the brakes have a lever ratio of roughly 1:3, which says we can assume a conservative estimate of 2200N of maximum force applied to the cable stop (if you're a 95th percentile male, squeezing at maximum grip strength in test settings that is!). I'm pretty sure this is within the capabilities of commercially available rivets (the fact that these things are even available for sale, not to mention being commonly used on carbon road bikes is testament to that!).